# Magento 2 : How to Disable/Enable Custom Shipping Method Based on State / Region

Tags: shipping, magento-2.1.3, regions

I want to show my custom shipping method based on state/region.

Comment: Please share your code?.

Comment: https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-custom-shipping

Answer (score 1):

If you want disable or enable shipping method for example UPS or flatrate based on Region ID then yo need to rewrite class: Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping in your custom module and add this code in method: collectCarrierRates

```
    $regionId = $request->getDestRegionId();
    $yourRegionId1 = 569;
    $yourRegionId2 = 583;
    if($regionId == $yourRegionId1 && $carrierCode == "ups"){
        $result = false;
    }

    if($regionId != $yourRegionId2 && $carrierCode == "flatrate"){
        $result = false;
    }
```

Note: You can take the region id from table: directory_country_region

Answer (score 0):

Every shipping method class has a method `collectRates()` and from this method, respective availability, shipping price or rate are managed.

If you will check it's the parameter 
`$request` and then you will see that parameter has currently selected shipping address's `country id and Region Id, City, postcode`.

> - $request->getCountryId() // country id $
> - request->getRegionId() //    region id
> - $request->getCity() // city id
> - $request->getPostcode() //postcode id

Comment: How to get when a customer has no address & customer come first time in the store.

Comment: **for calculating shipping should have an address which may be the new address or  existing shipping address**

Comment: Issue with new address

Comment: Can you be more explicit with some example?